# List all embedded resources in a folder

Tags: c#, wpf, resources

In my solution a had a folder with a few files. All this files have the Build Action "Embedded Resource".

With this code I can get a file:

```
assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(assembly.GetName().Name + ".Folder.File.txt");
```

But is there any way to get all `*.txt` files in this folder? A list of names or a method to iterate through them all?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You could check out

```
assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()
```

which returns an array of strings of all the resources contained. You could then filter that list to find all your `*.txt` files stored as embedded resources.

See [MSDN docs for `GetManifestResourceNames`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcenames) for details.

Comment: for some reason in `VB.net`, the output does not contain the folder names in which the resource is present vs C#

Answer (score 25):

Try this, returns an array with all *.txt* files inside **Folder** directory.

```
private string[] GetAllTxt()
{
    var executingAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    string folderName = string.Format("{0}.Resources.Folder", executingAssembly.GetName().Name);
    return executingAssembly
        .GetManifestResourceNames()
        .Where(r => r.StartsWith(folderName) && r.EndsWith(".txt"))
        //.Select(r => r.Substring(folderName.Length + 1))
        .ToArray();
}
```

NOTE: Uncomment the `//.Select(...` line in order to get the filename.

Comment: this should be the answer, it gives precise answer to OP's question

Answer (score 7):

have a try with this. here you get all files

```
string[] embeddedResources = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(T)).GetManifestResourceNames();
```

T is of course your type. so you can use it generic

Answer (score -3):

Just cracked this, use:

```
Assembly _assembly;
_assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
List<string> filenames = new List<string>();
filenames = _assembly.GetManifestResourceNames().ToList<string>();
List<string> txtFiles = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0; i < filenames.Count(); i++)
{
    string[] items = filenames.ToArray();
    if (items[i].ToString().EndsWith(".txt"))
    {
        txtFiles.Add(items[i].ToString());
    }
}
```