# Get a list of resource text files

Tags: c#

I have several .txt files attached to my project (see [How to embed a text file in a .NET assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433171/how-to-embed-a-text-file-in-a-net-assembly)).

How can I get a list of these files?  I'd like to write some code like this:

```
 foreach (string textfile in thisprogram.Resources.TextFiles) {
      if (textfile.Contains(x)) { /* etc. */ }
 }
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8208289/list-all-embedded-resources-in-a-folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you trying to determine if it's a text file based on the Type of 'System.String' or the name being "TextFile1"?  I'm not sure if there's exactly a way to do it based on the fact that it's a text file.  This will show all string resources (Text File and String resources), does that work?:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Resources;
using System.Globalization;

ResourceSet resourceSet = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, true, true);
foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in resourceSet)
{
    if (entry.Value is string)
    {
        if (entry.Value.ToString().Contains(x)) { /* etc. */ }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I get access to the type `ResourceSet`?  Is there a `using` I need?