# Dynamically generating available localizations from resource file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, localization, embedded-resource, resx

I have a MVC website which is using [`.resx` files for localization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1142802/how-to-use-localization-in-c-sharp).  However, the current behavior for determining *which* localizations are supported requires iterating over the physical `.resx` files, and they don't exist once the site has been compiled for publishing.

The folder structure is currently:

> - Language Resources
>
>   - Resource.en-US.resx
>   - Resource.fr-CA.resx
>   - Resource.hi.resx
>   - Resource.resx

Trying to get the list of all the resource files via `GetManifestResourceNames()`, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8208297/298754), only produces the single `LanguageResources.Resource.resources` file that represents the master, unlocalized list.  It may or may not have the localizations embedded into it, but there's no way I've found to see that.

**How can I tell at runtime that I support three languages?**

<sub>The end goal is to build a dropdown based on these three values.  If there's another way I should be approaching this problem, answers which address that are also acceptable.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Following the sidebar links for my question, I eventually found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/553244/298754), and Hans Holzbart's [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11047894/298754), which I'm reproducing below.  The question itself is approaching it from a different direction, but the answer is equally applicable to my situation.

```
// Pass the class name of your resources as a parameter e.g. MyResources for MyResources.resx
ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager(typeof(MyResources));

CultureInfo[] cultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures);
foreach (CultureInfo culture in cultures)
{
    try
    {
        ResourceSet rs = rm.GetResourceSet(culture, true, false);
        // or ResourceSet rs = rm.GetResourceSet(new CultureInfo(culture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName), true, false);
        string isSupported = (rs == null) ? " is not supported" : " is supported";
        Console.WriteLine(culture + isSupported);
    }
    catch (CultureNotFoundException exc)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(culture + " is not available on the machine or is an invalid culture identifier.");
    }
}
```

For my purposes, I had to filter out the Invariant culture with `.Where(x => x.Name != "")`, but other than that, this worked great.