# Xamarin Forms: read files names in a folder

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, directory

In the app that I am developing I need to create a different button for each file contained into a directory in Xamarin.Forms, and each button Text needs to correspond to a different file name.
Example: in my Xamarin.Forms project I have a folder called "Sounds", in that folder I have 4 mp3 file "Hello.mp3, Theme.mp3, Ring.mp3, Blop.mp3". So in that scenario what I need is to create 4 different buttons with text "Hello.mp3" for button 1, "Theme.mp3" for button 2 etc...
So I need to be able to read all the files name in a particular folder.
Is there a way to do that in Xamarin Forms?

Comment: Directory.GetFiles()

Comment: @Jason I am not sure that the function Directory.GetFiles() will work even after compiling and deploying the app to the device... Because i've seen in documentation that the the path needs to be a string in the form of "c:\", and after deploying the app to an actual device that path will no longer exist in that format

Comment: of course it works - you just have to use a file path appropriate to the system you're running on.

Comment: @Jason And how can I retrieve it based on different system (iOS/Android)?

Comment: which project are you putting the files in (shared project or platform project)?

Comment: In a folder in shared project (Forms)

Comment: I don't believe that .NET Standard library project have any mechanism to include files.  You could try including them as embedded resources instead of files.

Comment: And where should I store the files to be able to easily read them? In my app I need to be able to play different sounds from a folder, but I don't know how many audio files are there and lately I may be able to download them from an url (so they won't be preloaded in the app). Any idea?

Comment: To be more clear, I am trying to create like a soundoard application, with some pre loaded audios that will be present in the app since the installation and with some other that can be downloaded lately

Comment: as I already mentioned, you could include them as embedded resources.  Or if you really need them as files, put them in each platform project instead of the shared project

Comment: Ok and is there a way to automatically include them as embedded resources without right clicking each of them, assuming that I will be downloading them from an url afterwards? And then, how will the directory path be called if I store them in shared project? Sorry but it is the first time that I am working with files and file system in Xamarin

Comment: including them as resources shouldn't be any different than including them as files.  There are numerous existing questions about how to load embedded resources from a library.  It would probably make sense to copy the resources to a writable folder at run time, then you could download your other files to that same folder.

Comment: Oh right, good suggestion to copy them to a writable folder, thanks. So considering that I have these embedded resources, returning to the main question, how can I read all the names of embedded resources contained into a folder?

Comment: as I said before, this has been asked numerous times.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8208289/list-all-embedded-resources-in-a-folder

Comment: Oh right sorry, thank you, you really helped me a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using a StackLayout with name "_stackLayout" in your XAML, you can add this in your constructor of your CS page

```
foreach (var file in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles({DirectoryPath})
{
    AddButton(file.ToString());
};
```

And then just add this function below the constructor

```
public void AddButton(string name)
{
    _stackLayout.Children.Add(new Button() { Text = name });
}
```

Comment: I am not sure that the function Directory.GetFiles() will work even after compiling and deploying the app to the device... Because i've seen in documentation that the the path needs to be a string in the form of "c:\", and after deploying the app to an actual device that path will no longer exist in that format

Comment: Place a breakpoint and see what is returned by Directory.GetFiles(). From there’s it’s a piece of cake :)